# OneSignal not working on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, onesignal

I am working on a react native app (detached) and tried to install OneSignal for push notification, it works perfectly fine on android, but I am having issues on ios.

Initially I got this error: **'React/RCTAnimationType.h'** file not found.
Then after googling the error, I saw that I need to specify OneSignal into pod file(OneSignal documentation doesn't say about this, or I missed it).

After I added the following into pod file:

```
pod 'react-native-onesignal', 
        :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'
```

then it complained about pod spec something, well I found this file as well on their GitHub OneSignal repo.

so I changed as:

```
pod 'react-native-onesignal', 
        :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/react-native-onesignal.podspec",
        :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'
```

Run the command **pod install**

Looked like it resolved something but then I get another error as following:

https://github.com/danieljvdm/react-native-onesignal/blame/620717a0027538999cd98e1f225d0e4d9a804445/react-native-onesignal.podspec

> [!] Error installing react-native-onesignal [!] /usr/local/bin/git
>   clone
>   git+https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal.git.git
>   /var/folders/hp/96xj1gkj76s_x7hbh3rd2vs80000gn/T/d20180504-46105-1fdo6c6
>   --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch v3.1.4
>
> Cloning into
>   '/var/folders/hp/96xj1gkj76s_x7hbh3rd2vs80000gn/T/d20180504-46105-1fdo6c6'...
>   fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'git+https'

My final podfile looks as below:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'my app' do
  pod 'ExpoKit',
    :git => "http://github.com/expo/expo.git",
    :tag => "ios/2.4.4",
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "CPP",
      "GL"
    ]

  pod 'React',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :inhibit_warnings => true,
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "ART",
      "RCTActionSheet",
      "RCTAnimation",
      "RCTCameraRoll",
      "RCTGeolocation",
      "RCTImage",
      "RCTNetwork",
      "RCTText",
      "RCTVibration",
      "RCTWebSocket",
      "DevSupport",
      "CxxBridge"
    ]
  pod 'yoga',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'DoubleConversion',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'Folly',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'glog',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'react-native-onesignal', 
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/react-native-onesignal.podspec",
    :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.main_group.tab_width = '2';
    installer.pods_project.main_group.indent_width = '2';

    installer.pod_targets.each do |target|

    if target.pod_name == 'ExpoKit'
      target.native_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'EX_DETACHED=1'

        # needed for GoogleMaps 2.x
        config.build_settings['FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= []
        config.build_settings['FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS'] << '${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks'
        config.build_settings['FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS'] << '${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks'
      end
    end


    if ['Amplitude-iOS','Analytics','AppAuth','Branch','CocoaLumberjack','FBSDKCoreKit','FBSDKLoginKit','FBSDKShareKit','GPUImage','JKBigInteger2'].include? target.pod_name
      target.native_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
    # Build React Native with RCT_DEV enabled
    next unless target.pod_name == 'React'
    target.native_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'RCT_DEV=1'
    end

    end
  end
end
```

I just have the feeling that I am doing too much of what needs to be done maybe, can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Forgot to mention, I linked the library using **react-native link react-native-onesignal** for both android and iOS before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented onesignal in 1 of my project and it's running perfectly fine, i didn't installed with pods, i've implemented with this blog help, and it did perfectly fine with both android and ios.

[OneSignal Push Notification in React Native Blog](https://medium.com/differential/react-native-push-notifications-with-onesignal-9db6a7d75e1e)

Hope this will help you out, if you need any help just ask me.

Comment: @Mizlul without looking at project i can't say about that, but may be you have done more than what is required, you can go through the blog, what i can find right now is because of pods it's conflicting, as i can see many files does not be included in podfile as they already exist